# rtl8723be high power power consume Ubuntu 15 and 16

Tags: drivers, power-management, rtl8723be

i am using [this driver](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/)

power-consuming by powertop is:

```
10.1 W    9.3 pkts/s   Device   Network interface: wlp4s0 (rtl8723be)
```

i think this driver had some problem and that is cause of this problem.
how can i revert to original driver of ubuntu.

what can i do make it better.

ps. TLP installed and it doesn't help to less power using

Comment: If you revert to the original driver, it simply won't work.

Comment: @Pilot6 You might be able to run `sudo make uninstall` or `sudo dkms uninstall` before re-installing the native drivers.

Comment: I wonder if it's not driver specific. Could be related to this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/728019/laptop-battery-started-discharging-rapidly-in-15-10-even-during-suspend-powert